# JSONcpp iterate through a list within the object

Tags: c++, json

My json object has a list in it and I would like to iterate through the elements of the list
I saw the following post [Iterating through objects in JsonCpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800605/jsoncpp-iterate-thru-all-the-objects) , but this did not work for me

My json object:

```
{
         "name": ["str1",str2" ... ]
}
```

The code that I have and is not working

```
Json::Value names= (*json)["name"];
for( Json::ValueIterator itr = names.begin() ; itr != names.end() ; itr++ ) {
    string name =  *itr.asString();}
```

I am getting the following error

```
cannot convert from 'Json::Value' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>
```

I am sure the elements are string because calling `string name = names= (*json)["name"][0].asString()` is working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see how you can get a `cannot convert` error from your code, but I do think I see the problem.

`Json::ValueIterator` is an *iterator*; in other words, similar to a pointer, it needs to be dereferenced to access the value it points to.

- `itr.asString()` tries to access the `asString` method *of the iterator*, and the iterator doesn't have an `asString` method.
- `*itr.asString()` tries to access the `asString` method of the iterator then dereference the result (because of order of operations; `.` has a higher precedence than `*`), and the iterator doesn't have an `asString` method.
- `(*itr).asString()` (using parentheses to clarify precedence) or `itr->asString()` (using the `->` operator, the preferred approach) should work.

Comment: You're welcome.  However, you should use `itr->` instead of `(*itr).`; they mean the same thing, but `->` is cleaner and is the universally accepted style.

Comment: Are you sure about itr->asString()? I am getting type 'Json::ValueIterator' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry; I hadn't tested it myself. So `->` is cleaner and is the almost universally accepted style, and I'd consider it a mistake or bug in JsonCpp to not support it, but since it doesn't, use `(*itr).`.

Answer (score 9):

In c++11 its even simpler now:

```
for (auto itr : json["name"]) {
    string name = itr.asString();
    // ...
}
```