# jsonccp Array iteration

Tags: json, c++builder, jsoncpp

How can I iterate through JSON array using jsoncpp?
As an example:

```
{"val1":[
    {"val2":"_val2"},
    {"val3":"_val3"},
    {"val4":"_val4"}
        ]
 }
```

How to get _val2,_val3,_val4 in loop using this library?

Comment: you can read through wiki to see how its done: https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/wiki

Comment: yes, it was fast decision to ask this question.
solved issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913371/jsoncpp-iterate-through-a-list-within-the-object